# How to have comma separated input using ngModel and push to array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have email template where i have cc option , so for cc i want user to add email address with comma separated then push it to array `$scope.notifyCtrl.cc`. How i can achieve this task using angularjs 1.5 and above ?
main.html

```
<div layout="row">
    <md-input-container flex="100">
        <label>Cc</label>
        <input ng-model="notifyCtrl.cc">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.notifyCtrl = {};
$scope.notifyCtrl.cc = [];
```

Comment: what do you mean by `with comma separated` ? like this : a,b,c,@,... ?

Comment: @ThanhTùng `abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com` like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngList will do exactly what you want

**Text input that converts between a delimited string and an array of strings. The default delimiter is a comma followed by a space - equivalent to ng-list=", ". You can specify a custom delimiter as the value of the ngList attribute - for example, ng-list=" | ".**

Comment: Thanks ng-list helped to achieve the task.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use ng-change directive for this:

```
//ctrl.js
$scope.tempData = "";
$scope.func= ()=>{
    let arr = $scope.tempData.split(',');
    ...
};

//index.html
<div layout="row">
    <md-input-container flex="100">
        <label>Cc</label>
        <input ng-model="notifyCtrl.cc" ng-change="func()">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput)
to enter multiple string in an input separate by comma and them push all string into an array